# Nopcommerce shop configuration

Tags: nopcommerce

I'm working on my first NC shop(online Perfumery) version 3.30.

I added two main categories: 'Ladies' and 'Gentlemen' and i also added some manufacturers:

[image]

Now, ofter selecting one of the main categories, the user sees all products that are mapped to that main category and on the left side of the page, is the manufacturers list available(that is what i want). But here, ofter clicking one of the manufacturers, are all the products of that manufacturer listed(both 'Ladies' products as the products of Gentlemen). This is not good. what i want, is that here only the products are listed, that are mapped to the selected main category and not All products of that manufacturer.

How can i get this good?

Comment: Unfortunately out of the box, NopCommerce doesn't support viewing product lists filtered by category and manufacturer - only one or the other. Quite a lot of custom development is needed to get the functionality working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should consider wrapping these in some `if` statements. Here is a C# example:

```
if (genderLSelected == true)
 { <Code to display products for ladies>}
else if (genderMSelected == true)
 {<code to display products for men>}
else
 {<code to display all products>}
```

The buttons would have to have an `onClick` method for changing those bools - another `if` statement would do well here. Also, you'd need to write some code to stop both genders being selected at the same time. You could include this in the `onClick` methods for your buttons.

Comment: I could do that, but i'm not sure if this is the right way. I think i have a configuration issue and hope to get some good advice.

Comment: @Djave I think the idea behind nopCommerce, from what I can see, is to allow you to make your own code to a template, thereby decreasing your workload. With that in mind, I'd suggest at least trying this method.

Comment: I'm agree with u, but in this case im sure that i have bad design/configuration.

Comment: @Djave You misunderstand my point: Whether or not your design is good or bad, the usage of an `if` statement will work to your requirements. Don't worry about the design just yet, worry about making it work.

Comment: The question is far broader than this - it involves changing some core logic across various aspects of the codebase such as the controller logic, URL routing and view model.

Comment: @StevenSproat Don't drown the lad!

Comment: @Wolfish I meant that it's not just a simple case of "add a few if conditions", there's a lot of moving pieces at play.

Comment: @StevenSproat I imagine the pages for most sorts of criteria are included in this kind of package (I had a brief look myself - there's a lot of templates). I just read your comment, too, and whilst you're right about templates for *category* and *manufacture*, the concept is fairly workable. I managed to create multiple criteria buttons in about an hour the other night, and that was a fresh copy of nop.